# Fondo Blur al llegar advertencia

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy haciendo una pagina, quiero poner el efecto Blur cuando llegue un cuadro de alerta, estoy usando html para hacerlo

Estoy intentando usar un ejemplo que encontré en una pagina pero no me funciona

```js
    function addBlur() {
      $(‘#main’).addClass(‘blur’);
      $(‘#t_TreeNav’).addClass(‘blur’);
    }
```

```css
 .body {
      heigh: 665px;
      background-image: url(https://carontestudio.com/img/caronte-web-estudio-logo.png");
      background-size: 10rem;
    }

    .blur {
      flex-grow: 1;
      filter: blur(8px);
      -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
```

```html
<body>
      <h2>This is a sample paragraph.</h2>
    </body>
```

lo que quiero hacer es que cuando llegue un cuadro de alerta se aplique el efecto a toda la pantalla
¿Podrían ayudarme?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Buen día, por favor, adjunta un ejemplo [mínimo, reproducible y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Por favor, comparte también el HTML (no todo, sólo el código mínimo para poder reproducir el problema, como indicó otro usuario).

Comment: ya edite la publicacion, espero este bien, muchas gracias por los consejos.

Comment: @Saza.P la pregunta no fue editada.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro, una disculpa, creo que no se edito pero ya lo hice

Comment: Ojo también a dos cosas: es _height_, no _heigh_, y no son lo mismo los caracteres `‘’` que `'`... (de hecho, esto último es notorio en el snippet porque no está resaltando las cadenas en la sección de JS)

Comment: muchas gracias a todos, me ha sido de utilidad!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fácilmente puedes hacerlo así, el orden consiste en el siguiente:

- Llamas a la función `alerta()`.
- Al ingresar a la función `alerta()`, llamas a la función `agregarBlur()`, que agrega la clase `blur` al `body`.
- Y luego de 10 milisegundos, entra al `Timeout()`, mostrando el `alert`.
- El `alert` espera a que le des a `aceptar` para que se continúen las líneas de código, y así, al dar a `aceptar`, llamas a `removerBlur()` (ya que está debajo del `alert`), que quita la clase `blur` al `body`.

---

Ejemplo:

```js
function agregarBlur() {
  document.body.classList.add('blur');
}

function removerBlur() {
  document.body.classList.remove('blur');
}

function alerta() {
  agregarBlur(); // llamo a esta función que agrega la clase "blur"
  
  // luego de 10 milisegundos, entro al timeout...
  setTimeout(function() {
    alert('apliqué el blur'); // luego muestro el alert, y al dar aceptar...
    removerBlur(); // llamo a esta función que elimina la clase "blur"
  }, 10);
}
```

```css
body {
  heigh: 665px;
  background-image: url(https://carontestudio.com/img/caronte-web-estudio-logo.png");
  background-size: 10rem;
}

.blur {
  flex-grow: 1;
  filter: blur(8px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2>This is a sample paragraph.</h2>
  <button onclick="alerta()">mostrar alerta</button>
</body>
```